# Understanding TimeSeriesDataSet in Pytorch-Forecasting

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, forecasting, pytorch-forecasting

I have 913000 rows data:

[data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJC69.png)

First, Let me explain this data

this data is sales data for 10 stores and 50 item from 2013-01-01 to 2017-12-31.

i understand why this data has 913000, by leap year.

anyway, i made my training set.

```
training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    train_df[train_df.apply(lambda x:x['time_idx']<=training_cutoff,axis=1)],    
    time_idx = "time_idx",
    target = "sales",
    group_ids = ["store","item"], # list of column names identifying a time series
    max_encoder_length = max_encoder_length,
    max_prediction_length = max_prediction_length,
    static_categoricals = ["store","item"],
    # Categorical variables that do nat change over time (e.g. product length)
    time_varying_unknown_reals = ["sales"],
    
)
```

Now
First Question: i have known as the TimeSeriesDataSet has data param, reflected data minus prediction horizon by training_cutoff and minus max_encoder_length for prediction. this is right? if no please tell me truth.

Second Question: Similarly, this is output of over code
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7TzB.png)
Why the length is 863500

i calculate the length on my knowledge.

prediction horizon by training_cutoff - 20*50*10 =10000

max_encoder_length for prediction - 60*50*10 = 30000

Thus 913000-40000 = 873000.

where is 9500?

i do my best in googling. please tell me truth..

Comment: I solve this problem! if you want to know that please email to me (dsd0919@naver.com)

Comment: Dear @sungjonlee, you can answer your own question